# OpenGL: Turning on and off Lights

Tags: c++, opengl, if-statement, counter, light

I'm writing a program where I have a little "polyman" guy dancing at `0,-3`. I've colored him white, and am now trying to get a disco-like scene going, I have created a blue and red light, and am trying to alternate them by using a counter and and `if` and `else` statement. This is all in my `renderscene`

```
float ambientlight[] = {0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0};
float diffuselight[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float specular[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float lightpos[] = {0.0,10.0,0.0,1.0};  //light 1
float specref[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float spotdir[]={0.0,-10.0,0.0};

float rectX[6][5], rectY[6][5], rectZ[6][5];

float ambientlight2[] = {1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
float diffuselight2[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float specular2[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float lightpos2[] = {0.0,10.0,0.0,1.0}; //light 2
float specref2[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
float spotdir2[]={0.0,-10.0,0.0};


glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0,0,540,440);
glOrtho(-7.0,7.0,-7.0,7.0,5.0,-5.0);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
if (counterForLights % 2 == 0)   //if counter even
{
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,lightpos);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,ambientlight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuselight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,10.0);  //light 1
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,15.0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,spotdir);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    counterForLights++;
}
else  //if counter odd
    {

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_AMBIENT,ambientlight2);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuselight2);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPECULAR, specular2);
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,10.0);
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,15.0);  //light2
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,spotdir2);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        counterForLights++;
    }
```

`counterForLights` is a global variable equalling `1`. It runs, but doesn't ever show the red light, just the blue light. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong here?

Also, if you need to see anymore of my code just let me know! :)

Comment: As fas as I can tell, the only thing "red" about the second light is the ambient part. Since in a typical material, the ambient coefficients are very low, the effect of it will be minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're enabling light 0, then enabling light 1, then never disabling either, ever again. So from the second frame onwards, lighting should be constant. Probably smarter to stick to and update light 0, or else to load the coefficients once and then perform an enable and a disable in either conditional branch.

Comment: Awww I see now, so in theory I could use the same principle using the counter, but only have `Light0` and then use an `if counter is even, glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,ambientlight)` and then the `else` would be `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,ambientlight2);` ?

Comment: Yes — OpenGL is a lot of global state; if you've enabled a light then it stays enabled for all time until you say otherwise. But it's just a numbered slot. So you can update the information in that slot if it's more convenient, rather than having different data in different slots and switching between them. A rule of thumb in OpenGL is that fewer calls is faster code but, honestly, if you're using the fixed pipeline anyway then I don't think it's going to make much odds. It'd be premature optimisation at best.

Answer (score 1):

```
else  //if counter odd
{

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_AMBIENT,ambientlight2);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuselight2);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPECULAR, specular2);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,10.0);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,15.0);  //light2
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,spotdir2);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    counterForLights++;
}
```

It doesn't look like you're specifying a position for LIGHT1.

Also, I'm going to /strongly/ advise against using the Fixed-Function-Pipeline for drawing in OpenGL. [There's lots of tutorials online for transitioning to modern OpenGL.](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Introduction)

Comment: I want the lights coming from the same location

Comment: Great. You still need to expressly define the position of LIGHT1. You only defined it for LIGHT0.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you're saying now